# Cant subract form count

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to get the total number of `<input>`'s and I'm having no issue doing so. Now I'm trying to subtract the total number of inputs from the total number of errors. But for some reason I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bad is not defined

In the console. Here's my code

```
$("#a").on('click', function () {
    var bad = 0;
    $('.form :text').each(function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") bad++;

    });

    if (bad > 0) $('.congrats').css("display", "block").text(bad + ' missing');
    else $('.congrats').hide();

});
//Get total inputs
console.log(form.getElementsByTagName('input').length);
//Minus total inputs
console.log(form.getElementsByTagName('input').length - bad);
```

As you can see at the last line I'm trying to subtract. Any ideas?

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ ... you might not care how your code is formatted, but if you expect others to read your code, please indent it properly.

Comment: You might want to learn how [variables are scoped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope). But *even if* `bad` was accessible, there is also a problem with your logic: Your are binding the event handler and then your immediately logging a value trying to use `bad`. But at that moment, the event handler wasn't even executed. It is only executed when the user clicks on `#a`. To achieve what you want, you have to move the `console.log` statements *inside* the event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bad is defined inside the click function.

Your console.log is outside of this function and therefore bad is out of scope.

To fix this you would need to move your console.log statements inside the click function or move the variable outside of the click function.